# Displaying MsgBox when range of cells have not a specific length

Tags: excel, msgbox, vba

I have a program in which a label is scanned and that value goes into a cell, but for security reasons, it's necessary to check that the length of this is always the same (for example: 8, label=12345-78) the string has a "-" in it. What I want the program to do is that, when the scanned label has a number different than this one, display a messagebox that indicates that the number is invalid and then erase the cell's content. I would really appreciate some help with this.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'macro para prohibir longitud que no sea la seleccionada

Dim rango As Range


For Each Range In Worksheets("HojadeInspection").Range("I9:I20")


If rango.Len(c.Value) <> 8 Then

MsgBox "La longitud del código insertado no es la correcta", vbcrtical


End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Data, Data Validation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "write my code for me" website...please show what you have tried and any code you have already written.

Comment: Hi, I' tried with data validation, but, since the data is pasted into the cell and not typed, it doesn't work.

Comment: I already posted the one I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim i As Integer

'I is the column I used, switch it to meet your needs

i = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I:I").Cells. _
     SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

If Not Len(Range("I" & CStr(i))) = 8 Then

MsgBox "Your Message Here", vbCritical
End If

End Sub
```

(Code edited from original response)

Comment: It works, but here's how the program I am making works: I scan a label and that number goes to cell I9, then I scan another one and it goes to I10 and so on. So, with this program, at the moment of inserting the first one, it evaluates all the range, getting the message always because i haven't filled the rest of the cells. Is there a way where I could evaluate them only after the cell is filled? Also, I have another macro in my "Worksheet_Change", which causes the program to detect and ambiguous name.

Comment: This should do the trick. How you want to get the code to execute is up to you, but this counts all of the cells that have valid data then goes to a cell with the coordinates of the highest integer. It worked fine for me. **Note: This assumes that you have valid data in all of your cells, so plan accordingly**

Comment: For some reason, the message appears even if I introduce a string of 8 numbers.

Comment: If you're including the "-" then you need to change the 8 to a 9.

Comment: No, I already tried without it and another combinations. I think that the problem is in the definition of the variable "i".

Comment: I used this code pretty much verbatim to do what you're describing, maybe there are some null values in the column? If there are this will not work as needed

Comment: I tried it on a new document and after that, I tried by in my document by changing it to the range I want("I:I") to ("B9:B20") and the Len(Range("I") to "B" and after that to "B9:B20"). Still no changes in result.

Comment: As long as you have `dim i as integer` included at the top I don't see why it wouldn't work. `i` should equal the number of cells that aren't blank in your desired row, and then `range("I" & Cstr(i))` should select the bottom-most cell, which is what the `if` statement hinges on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'macro para prohibir longitud que no sea la seleccionada
    Dim forCell As Variant

    For Each forCell In Worksheets("HojadeInspection").Range("I9:I20")
        If Not forCell.Value Like "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]" Then
            MsgBox "La longitud del código insertado no es la correcta", vbcrtical
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I already tried it, but after it detects the error, the message keeps appearing infinitely, even if I close it.

Comment: It can not appear infinietely because loop is finite. So the message can pop up at most 12 times (as many as there are cell in a range).

Comment: Ok, I think that I got a little problem that might be easy to change. I made another macro that looks for that number and displays a message if it's repeated in the database. This is also stored as "private sub worksheet_change (ByVal target As Range)

What could be a way to put this sub that you made without using the same name, because if I repeat it, a message displaying "ambiguous name" appears, but if I insert it without putting that sub, this the error mentioned will appear.